# Employee Web Usage From Proxy Logs

Tags: reporting

I need to find/create an application that will create employee web usage reports from HTTP proxy logs.  Does anyone know of a good product that will do this?

*@Joe Liversedge - Good point. I don't have to worry about this, however, as I am the only person in my company with the know-how to pull off an SSH tunnel.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a scenario: What's to stop two employees, let's call them 'Eric' and 'Tim', from running their own little SSH tunnel back home to prevent 'the Man', in this case *you*, from narc'ing out their use of the Internet. Now you have a useless report.

If you're serious about getting real data, you'll want something close to the pipes.

But agreed, [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) would work pretty well, as would an over-long and unmaintainable Perl script or a series of `awk`s, `sort`s, `uniq -c`'s, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use it, but I hear [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) is a really good log aggregation and reporting tool. It comes recommended by my sysadmin buddys, I just haven't had a need for it, since we use, IndexTools for our usage stats.

Answer (score 0):

or Sensage... which has a more formalized model {more like a normal relational database} of data - at the expense of requiring a little more thought and setup cost to start consuming logs.

I don't think that they offer a free low-volume version like splunk do though.